# Building a SAN on 2012R2 "Storage Spaces" - More Cores, or Faster Single Thread?

Tags: storage-area-network, central-processing-unit, windows-server-2012-r2, storage-spaces

I am considering building a SAN unit on Server 2012R2 using Storage Space. In that situation is it more helpful to have more CPU cores, or less faster cores?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Pretty irrelevant - as in: you can go for a midrange CPU and get enough power these days for a SAN. Go for price (and power envelope as this implies cooling).

THAT SAID: Make sure you know what you want to do with the storage spaces. There stil are  serious issues with performance when using a raid parity setup. If you need fast write in  Raid volume you basically are out of luck. Resizing also is limited (no rebalancing of content). If you can live with these limitations... things are ok.

Comment: I am planing on RAID 1+0 arrays of both SSDs, and Spindle based drives. No RAID 5-6-50-60. I guess I should have mentioned that. If it were all spindle drives I would no be concerned, but it is going to have 4-6 SSDs in it for speed.

Comment: Well then you need to read because StorageSpaces does NONE Of those - no Raid 1+0, no Raid 5, no Raid 6, No Raid 50 and No Raid 60. It has compatible things but they are not identical. It has raid similar mirroring but it IS NOT 1+0. You miss documentation basics. And mixing them is not possible as you know it either. But it supports in 2012 R2 tiering. Really, read the docs.

Comment: Yes, I am aware it is not RAID, I was using that as more of a analogy of how I plan to setup it up in my head. I am considering a 2 Way mirror of SSDs with a Hot Spare, and a similar setup for the spindle based drives.

Comment: You are aware of the tiering mechanism? I would rather go with that.

Comment: Yes, but I thought they could be used in unison. I was going to build a little test server with old hardware we have around the office before I bought anything, but for pricing I was wondering one question, and I guess I will simplify it. In a SSD array of discs, which is better, more cores, or faster cores?

Comment: No difference for a SAN unless you get about using an OLD ATOM. The processing is ridiculously low unless you go 10 gigabit or run Raid.